# Flutter Web shows blank page on GitHub deployment

Tags: flutter, build, github-pages, flutter-web

### Issue:

I created a web app in Flutter and deployed to the web using GitHub Pages. It worked on the first release (the page was functional, all content worked), and then I made some updates and attempted to redeploy and the web page now shows up blank. The screen is white. No content is displayed, and it only shows the generic title and favicon.

I am able to view the page normally when I run directly from Android Studio using Chrome. It is only when I deploy to the GitHub Pages that the screen is blank.

My process:

- Released using `flutter build web` command and also tried `flutter build web --release` and other combinations
- Moving code from Android Studio to GitHub Pages by uploading the contents of the build > web folder to the main branch

### What I have tried:

Every combination of modifying removing the  line that has been suggested in similar questions.

- Removing `<base href=...>`
- `<base href="/">`
- `<base href="./">`
- `<base href="/homepage/">`
- Removing and replacing the entire GitHub repo
- Building using `flutter build web --web-renderer html`
- Removing all complex code from the app itself, leaving just a banner

I have read every StackOverflow and GitHub page on this topic and no solution has worked. Looking for any help!

Here is my GitHub repo [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmelF.png)

And here is my index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.
    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.
    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->

  <!--<base href="/">-->

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="sports_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>sports_app</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = '1014210939';
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.5.0-10.0.pre.40, on macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta), locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.5.0-10.0.pre.40 on channel master at /Users/mikebeazer/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 20c4b6c53e (3 hours ago), 2022-10-23 15:22:39 -0400
    • Engine revision f62df69205
    • Dart version 2.19.0 (build 2.19.0-330.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.18.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mikebeazer/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 13C100
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 11.3.1 20E241 darwin-arm64 (Rosetta)
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the default on index.html

```html
 <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
```

And you need to change `base-href`, build like

```
flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href /your_repository_name/
```

For GitPage it is required to be this format

Comment: I changed the index.html to `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">` and rebuilt it using the build web line above. I still only see a blank page. The site is: https://jumpinsports.github.io/homepage/

Comment: What is your project name & repository name, same as repository name? Can you include your build command?

Comment: The project name is sports_app. Repository is called homepage. The build command I used is:
`flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href /homepage/`

Thank you for your help on this

Comment: is it ok on debug mode? also try with `sports_app` , i would prefer same name.

Comment: I created a repo called "sports_app" and tried again with that one (https://jumpinsports.github.io/sports_app/), but did not fix it. I am able to run it in debug and release mode through Android Studio, but still get the blank screen on GitHub Pages.

Comment: create a copy of this project and try `flutter create .` then build for web and deploy

Comment: No luck with using `flutter create .` either

Comment: can you include flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Please change href in the index.html file to below line then build again.

```
<base href="./">
```

**Method 2**

The  tag in your index.html. Change it to the base path of your github repo. In this case this would be

```
<base href="https://jumpinsports.github.io/sports_app/"/>
```

**Method 3**

If you have API Service in your project you must activate core service in your backend code.

Comment: I just tried this again. I modified the web>index.html line to `<base href="./"`. This has worked for me in the past. But I'm still getting a blank page now.

Comment: pls try method 2 and host again

Comment: I tried method 2 as well with no luck. I am still getting a blank page.

Comment: I saw your repo. Please remove the web folder from your repo. and upload all content inside from thE WEB folder. and host again

Comment: If you have api service pls activate core service

Comment: I had it with the web folder in one version since I couldn't get anything to work. There is no longer a web folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I switched to deployment with Firebase rather than GitHub Pages. That did not work initially, so I did an Inspect using Chrome and found a base href was missing. I and used `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">` in index.html

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74164558/9890577 worked for my end. Github repository name is needed when building the web app.